# Excel:Checking if a name appears in the last month within the same column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This is what my data looks like. The third column is my desired column.

```
Name    Month   Appears In previous month
John      1       NA
Michael   1       NA
Jenny     1       NA
Christine 2       No
Lenny     2       No
Michael   2       Yes
Steve     2       No
Will      3       No
Lenny     3       Yes
Barbara   3       No
```

Any ideas how can achieve such result in excel?

Comment: Your question is tagged as both VBA and formula, do you want both or do you have a preference?

Comment: @JoshuaRoss  
I prefer formulas. Should I take the VBA tag out?

Comment: It's not a big issue but for me, I am way stronger in VBA than formulas, so it helps to weed me out!

Comment: @JoshuaRoss I am totally open to a VBA solution by the way. That is why I put it there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a formula for cell C2:

```
=IF(B2=1,"NA",IF(COUNTIFS(A1:A$2,A2,B1:B$2,B2-1),"Yes","No"))
```

After entering it, just copy it downwards.

BTW, "Michael" is spelled two different ways in your sample data.  :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the countifs function to see how many instances appear for the previous month.

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,B2-1)
```

Countifs will let you add as many restrictions when counting as possible.  The restrictions this has is
1:  Does the name show up more than once.
2:  If it does show up more than once, then see if last month(current month-1) is in the list of filtered results.

If you want specific text, you can just surround it in an if statement to show the text you want.    Excel hero's answer shows how to do that.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!